# event not thrown in C++ with wxwidgets

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I've made a [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) form using [wxFormBuilder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/), and I'm trying to throw a mousewheel event on object. The problem is the event is not thrown, so I'd like to ask you if there should be some additional settings. The object has an event table like this

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyObj, wxScrolledWindow)
  EVT_MOUSEWHEEL(MyObj::OnMouseWheel)
END_EVENT_TABLE();
```

And it is initialized this way:

```
myObjInstance = new MyObj(this, ID_MYOBJ, wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(30,30), 0);
```

I noticed that in wxFormBuilder, when added an event from GUI, [function Connect](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandlerconnect) was used which generated this output

```
myObjInstance ->Connect( wxEVT_MOTION, wxMouseEventHandler( MyFrame::TestMouseOnverTheEdit ), NULL, this );
```

but I cannot use it as my event handler function OnMouseWheel is in class MyObj and it is protected.

I also made a frame with this object and event in [wxDev-C++](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/) and the event was thrown. The difference is that form created by wxFormBuilder has multiple sizers and panels, while form in wxDev-C++ don't have any. There was a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510313/not-catching-all-mouse-events-with-wxwidgets) solved, but I still don't know what should I do. Thanks.

Edit:
Signature of the handler:

```
void OnMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent & AwxEvent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. The thing is, that I had a wxPanel (inside a main frame)

```
m_panel = new wxPanel( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
```

and then I was adding myObj to the app like this:

```
myObjInstance = new MyObj(this, ID_MYOBJ, wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(30,30), 0);
```

which didn't work, so I set the first argument (parent window) to m_panel:

```
myObjInstance = new MyObj(m_panel , ID_MYOBJ, wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(30,30), 0);
```

and now it works ok with Event tables.

Answer (score 1):

"The problem is the event is not thrown,"

I imagine the event is indeed thrown.  Your problem is that it is not caught!

Here are some things you need to look into.

1. Your event handlers should be public.
2. What is MyObj?  It should be a specialization of wxFrame or some other standard wxWidgets window.

   BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyObj, wxScrolledWindow)

   This implies that MyObj is a specialization of wxScrolledWindow.  If it is not, as you suggest in your comment, then the event table will not work to catch the events.  http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Events#Inheriting_Event_Tables_.28Events_in_Derived_Classes.29
3. It is not clear whether you are using an event table, or the Connect() method.  You cannot use both!
4. If you do use connect, you need to be careful to use the correct object to call it.  In simple terms, the connect method on the frame that generated the event needs to be called, rather than the object that is handling the event.  http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Events#Using_Connect.28.29

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 1. I made the method OnMouseWheel public and tried myObjInstance ->Connect( wxEVT_MOTION, wxMouseEventHandler( MyObj::OnMouseWheel ), NULL, this ); with no change, or Connect has nothing to do with it? 2. MyObj is a special object which is not in standard wxWidgets library, but that shouldn't be the problem, because as I wrote earlier, the listener worked for this object when the form was created by wxDev-C++. 3. the signature is as you stated, void OnMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent & AwxEvent);

Comment: I haven't noticed you replied to me, because you just edited your post. Anyway, I'll reply to modified question number 2. - MyObj extends the wxScrolledWindow and I haven't suggested that it does not. I've said twice that the listener for it worked when the GUI was generated by wxDev-C++ (and I was also using event tables). 3. At first I didn't know that I can't use both event tables and Connect(). That should be all, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Connect()` you need to specify `wxEVT_MOUSEWHEEL`, not `wxEVT_MOTION`.